# Camera image not being added to an image list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I am using image_picker in my flutter app.

after taking a pic, i am adding it to a XFile List. but when checking the list length it is showing as null.

When I follow the route of first adding an image from gallery and then adding a image from camera then it seems to work fine. what is the correct way of adding the camera image to the list. my code  is follows:

```
List<XFile> ? _imageFileList;
List<XFile> ? pickedFile;
XFile ? file;


void getImageFile(ImageSource source, bool multimage) async {

if(multimage) {

  pickedFile = await _picker.pickMultiImage(maxWidth: double.infinity,
      maxHeight: double.infinity, imageQuality: 10);

  setState(() {

    _imageFileList = pickedFile;
    print('image selected');
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    Flushbar(

      message:  'length of imagelist ${_imageFileList?.length}',
      duration:  Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..show(context);

  });


} else{


 file = await _picker.pickImage(
  source: source, maxWidth: double.infinity,
  maxHeight: double.infinity, imageQuality: 10);

 setState(() {

 pickedFile?.add(file!) ;

 _imageFileList?.add(file!) ; //

 print('camera image selected');
 print('image selected');
 Navigator.of(context).pop();

 Flushbar(
   message:  'length of imagelist ${_imageFileList?.length}',
   duration:  Duration(seconds: 5),
 )..show(context);



 });



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in 'else' block you don't initialize _imageFileList. You are trying to add an item to an uninitialized list. Therefore, you can add image from camera after the gallery. Because in 'if' block it will be initialized.

There is 2 option:

1. `List<XFile> _imageFileList = <XFile>[];`
   and in 'if' block: `_imageFileList.addAll(pickedFile)` instead of `_imageFileList = pickedFile;`
2. In 'else' block: `if(_imageFileList == null) _imageFileList = <XFile>[]`
   In 'if' block: `if(_imageFileList == null) _imageFileList = <XFile>[]` and after that, `_imageFileList.addAll(pickedFile)`

For me, the option 1 is the best way to doing this.

Comment: thanks, will give this a try but the issue isn't on the multiimage select. it is on the camera source.

Comment: Exactly, because in multiImage you are initalizing the list. If you try camera source before the multiImage you have an uninitialized list, and you can't add an item to an uninitialized list. That's why it's null.